# Xcode 14.3 build error "unable to initiate PIF transfer session (operation in progress?)"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode14.3

Ran into this build error in Xcode 14.3 that prevents me from building my app.

> Build service could not create build operation: unknown error while handling message: MsgHandlingError(message: "unable to initiate PIF transfer session (operation in progress?)")

There isn't more detail than that--deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, resetting package caches did not help.

Any ideas?

I tried deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, and resetting package caches to no avail.

Answer (score 147):

**UPDATE: As some others have mentioned, this can be fixed by simply closing Xcode and re-opening it, then doing a regular build (Command+B) instead of running it. Give that a shot before trying the other options!**

The error seemed to be resolved by doing the following:

1. Close Xcode
2. Open finder, and delete the derived data folder: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Open finder, CMD+SHIFT+G and go to `~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm`. Right-click > Show Package Contents, and delete the `repositories` folder and `repositories.lock` file.
4. Open Xcode and let it build naturally

Coworker also resolved this by deleting derived data, rebuilding on Xcode 14.1 or 14.2, and then switching back to Xcode 14.3. Will try these steps again next time I see it to confirm if this is a reliable fix.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. In my case I just ran the following from bash:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/* && rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm`

Comment: Just doing steps 1 and 2 worked for me

Comment: Just closing and reopening Xcode worked for me, so doesn't seem related to derived data or spm

Comment: Closing and opening has worked for me multiple times. I came looking for a solution now, because the issue keeps happening every few days. Hope that the Derived Data cleaning solves the issue permanently.

Comment: This works for Xcode 15 Beta too.

Comment: Adding some addition to previous @JornRigter comment. I think we need to admit that Xcode never starts working as we would expect it to work! Apple has gave us tool to develop software, that itself needs development but for some reason some bugs are in there since the beginning of Xcode. BTW for me also just Xcode restart did it this time.

Comment: xcode15 is just worse. every time I install pod I have delete derived data and restart Xcode. time wasting

Comment: Flipping Xcode!

Answer (score 85):

Closing and opening Xcode seems to also remove this error.

Answer (score 27):

Deleting derived data, restarting Xcode and my MacBook wasn't working for me consistently. What does work for me is opening up `Activity Monitor` and kill the `XCBBuildService` process. That solved it for me. No need to restart or delete derived data when doing this.

Comment: This way works for my case. Xcode 15.2

Comment: Stupit development tools Apple!!!!  Thanks Paul...

Answer (score 5):

Close and open works for my case.

Answer (score 4):

The Error is appeared due to cache issue.
Restart mac and xcode can solved it OR

Open Xcode Setting ,
the Go to Location and click on Dervied Data and Delete All Derived data the clean and build the project error are gone

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is mostly due to some cache/pending process issue. Restarting Xcode works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Recently shifted to Xcode 15 and things became much worse :/ it literally appears almost every day... that works for me (not every time lol):

1. Close Xcode (sometimes when I close it manually and open Activity Monitor it still runs, so be sure to check)
2. Clean DD (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`)
3. Remove SPM folders from caches (`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm` and `rm -rf ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm`)
4. cd into your project folder and run xcodebuild on your xcodeproj file (be sure to have xcode tools installed) (it will look like `xcodebuild -project [YourProjectName].xcodeproj`). It will construct all of the SPM dependencies you need for your project.
5. Open Xcode and try to run, if your are lucky, it will arrange the build.

Comment: Upd - after hours of struggle also found another possible solution: you should have another project, might be small one, with at least one package imported.
Do steps 1-3 from above answer, open your small project, build it and get back to your main project, as shared spm folders are gonna update, sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Runs for me:

1. Close Xcode
2. Run into the project :

   rm -rf node_modules
   rm -f package-lock.json
   rm -f yarn.lock
   npm cache clean --force
   npm install
3. Open finder, and delete the derived data folder:
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
4. Open finder, CMD+SHIFT+G and go to
   ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm. Right-click > Show Package
   Contents, and delete the repositories folder and repositories.lock
   file.
5. Open Xcode CLEAN PREV BUILD and let it build naturally

Answer (score 1):

after deleting DerivedData folder and running Clean Build Folder, i still got the issue. i then restarted my macbook and now it works already.

Comment: restarting the mac works for me

Answer (score 1):

In **Xcode** `Version 15.1 (15C65)`, closing the app and opening it back up was not enough. These are the steps through which I went; Xcode --> Product tab at the top menu bar --> Clean Build Folder. Below is an image to help describe it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

worked for me I have react native project

Answer (score 1):

Xcode emitted this build error when I added an old unit test class back into the project. I then added a `@testable import NameOfMyModule` and the build succeeded. YMMV

Answer (score -1):

as I have mentioned in earlier answer  when ever I install pod I have to delete the derived data manually and restart Xcode which is time consuming . other question have similar solutions with those were not best. I want a permanent solution for this.

I have added this

```
"iPhone15": "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 15 Pro Max'",
```

command to the script of package.json so I have to just run this and do red to manually delete the Derived Data and restart Xcode . much time saving