# Xcode 15 build error "unable to initiate PIF transfer session (operation in progress?)"

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, xcode15

Showing Recent Messages

```
Build service could not create build operation: unknown error while handling 
message: MsgHandlingError(message: "unable to initiate PIF transfer session 
(operation in progress?)")
```

I have read out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980685/xcode-14-3-build-error-unable-to-initiate-pif-transfer-session-operation-in-pr) question which is the exact copy of this.but every time I install pod it through this error. deleting derived data every time is not to be the best solution. looking for some other solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 14.3 build error "unable to initiate PIF transfer session (operation in progress?)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980685/xcode-14-3-build-error-unable-to-initiate-pif-transfer-session-operation-in-pr)

Comment: @NicoHaase I have read the above question. but that does not have an answer. on Xcode15 every time I build I have to restart the Xcode and MacBook. too much time waste

Comment: If that other question is an **exact copy**, what would be the benefit of opening a new one? Not getting a solution from that other question is not a valid reason

Comment: that question was about xcode 14 and its about xcode 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try restart the XCode. I don't know but i tried

1. `Restart Xcode`
2. `flutter clean && flutter pub get && pod install`

It start working as normal.

Comment: as I have mentioned earlier when ever I install pod I have to delete the derived data manually and restart Xcode which is time consuming . other question have similar solutions with those were not best. I want a permanent solution for this.